# Can we use a fully qualified identifier in a module, without importing the module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

From [Dynamic linking in C/C++ (dll) vs JAVA (JAR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36646687/dynamic-linking-in-c-c-dll-vs-java-jar/36646911#36646911)

> > when i want to use this jar file in another project we use "package" or "import" keyword
>
> You don't have to. This is just a short hand.  You can use full
>   `package.ClassName` and there is no need for an `import`.  Note: this
>   doesn't import any code or data, just allow you to use a shorter name
>   for the class.
>
> e.g. there is no difference between
>
> ```
> java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> import java.util.Date();
>
> Date date = new Date(); // don't need to specify the full package name.
> ```

Is it the same case for `import` in Python3?

Can we use a identifier defined in a module, without importing its module? Did I miss something in the following to make that happen?

What differences are between Java and Python's `import`?

```
>>> random.randint(1,25)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'random' is not defined
>>> import random
>>> random.randint(1,25)
18
```

Comment: As your example demonstrates: no, you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is not Java. In Python you can only access names that are either builtins or defined in the current scope or it's parents scopes - the "top-level" scope being the module namespace (AKA "global" namespace).

The import statement (which is an executable statement FWIW) does two things: first load the module (this actually happens only once per process, then the module is cached in `sys.modules`), then bind the imported name(s) in the current scope. IOW this:

```
import foo
```

is syntaxic sugar for

```
foo = __import__("foo")
```

and

```
from foo import bar
```

is syntaxic sugar for

```
foo = __import__("foo")
bar = getattr(foo, "bar")
del foo
```

Also you have to understand what "loading a module" really means: executing all the code at the module's top-level.

As I mentionned, `import` is an executable statement, but so are `class` and `def` - the `def` statement creates a `code` object from the function's body and signature, then creates a `function` object with this code object, and finally bind this function object to the function's name in the current scope, the `class` statement does the same thing for a class (executing all the code at the "class" statement's top-level in a temporary namespace and using this namespace to create the "class" object, then binding the class object to it's name).

IOW, all happens at runtime, everything is an object (including functions, classes and modules), and everything you do with an `import`, `class` or `def` statement can be done "manually" too (more or less easily though - manually creating a function is quite an involved process).

So as you can see, this really has nothing to do with how either Java or C++ work.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, you can't implicitly import a module in Python by using a fully qualified name.

Slightly longer answer:

In Python, importing a module can have side effects: a module can have module-level code, not all of its code has to be wrapped in functions or classes. Therefore, importing modules at arbitrary and unexpected locations could be confusing, since it would trigger those side effects when you don't expect them.

The recommended style (see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ for details) is to put all your imports at the top of your module, and not to hide imports at unexpected places.

Comment: True, but the same things apply to Java classloading.

Comment: @user2357112 It's a long time since I actively wrote Java, but back then, everything had to be wrapped in a class, and I'm not aware that you can trigger Code execution simply by loading a class without either instantiating it or calling one of its static methods.

Comment: "I'm not aware that you can trigger Code execution simply by loading a class without either instantiating it or calling one of its static methods" - you can. Static field initializers and static initializer blocks can trigger arbitrary code.

Comment: I see, thanks. Although I guess both in Java and in Python, triggering random actions on import without a good reason are frowned upon.

Comment: I assume that Java resolves the name at compile time, and the initialization of the remote class therefore happens at startup, not when you first need the remote class. Which would be difficult to emulate in Python, where the import happens at execution time.

Comment: Java resolves things like "this `Date` means `java.util.Date`" at compile time, but initialization happens the first time a class is needed, and when that is is really hard to predict.